# Activeadmin login redirect towards devise login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

My activeadmin login page redirects towards devise login if it not login and also logout if devise user logout

Meanz it depends on devise login

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

In console this happens

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-15 16:24:19 +0500
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: What is your problem ? What do you want ?

Comment: I want it should follow its default behaviour meanz redirect towrards admin login path

Comment: Which path it redirects to ? It should be in console log, right after the lines, you posted here.

Comment: /users/login....

Comment: Did you made any other changes while integrating AA ? Like any customization to initializer or custom controller ?